# Batch Insert Array with Vertx JDBC Handler

Tags: java, jdbc, vert.x

I'm using JDBC lib of vertx and I need to batch insert values that contains an array field.

I have tried this :

```
 String query = "UPSERT INTO " + TABLENAME + " (ID, NODES) VALUES (?,?)";
            JsonArray param= new JsonArray();
            param.add(currentUser.getId().toString());
            param.add(new JsonArray(currentUser.getNodes()));
            List<JsonArray> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(param);
```

My Output :

```
    UPSERT INTO USER (ID, NODES) VALUES (?,?)
    [["4ec99c96-7ece-34df-9da0-c42e18f9ec51",["9385fe01-980b-3fb1-b911-7cc3a62c028b","1a05f21a-5278-3d2c-8ee1-b8fd44059e5b","a0b34f81-ef77-3eb2-9c81-8841b9277dd8","2e2ebd32-a7a9-38c8-9b35-b7d1c9b97335","7384ac4c-9796-38b1-8069-45bfc57f1beb","19afe185-8b2a-324e-a8e1-0861a0df8d40","e5efd51e-cc8f-348c-a975-5a25ac9f3321","b9bd2bf0-a581-31a5-a4ca-531cfd0420a1","97200212-af2a-3db9-bfe9-c7a9e09da278","919b6f2a-25f9-32d4-bae3-1a270a1e7e6d","a5271df9-aee2-36ae-85ff-b706cac8be2d","b9ad27fd-28b6-3463-b3e9-1e98e0e3c0e1","37c3790a-cd1d-3d1a-91e4-95fbcd25c592","d3b74229-5b18-3e3e-863e-1b56c2e024ba","331f9940-39ce-3af2-b9ba-cfb6d08066bf","14ee65c5-d48c-3c85-ae9e-639c918af5bd","f81898a1-aad9-34bf-ab3f-e7c314c74a81","48adeeeb-8301-39d3-bfd9-9e5557504b55","68f1d824-1c62-3d6d-a529-ef15cda96ad1"]]]
```

Before switching to prepared statement my working request was :

```
 String query = "UPSERT INTO " + TABLENAME + " (ID, NODES) VALUES ('id',ARRAY['1','2'])";



phoenixSharedJDBCClient.getConnection(conn -> {

            if (conn.succeeded()) {

                SQLConnection connection = conn.result();

                connection.batchWithParams(query,params, res -> {

                    if (res.succeeded()) {
                        resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(Boolean.TRUE));
                    } else if (res.failed()) {
                        resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Prepared statement request: "+res.cause().getMessage()));
                    }
                });
                connection.close();
            }
```

My database is Apache Phoenix a sql layer for Hbase.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently vert.x JDBC client is not able to handle arrays because the underlying JDBC API requires that the type of the data in the array is known at start and we have no way to detect it from JSON.

There was an attempt to solve this: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-jdbc-client/commit/3ea6103f4d698137da533522f2c3d4096522f8c6 but it is very RDBMS specific, it would work for Postgres because when dealing with empty arrays a `oid` reference is always accepted but there is no such thing (to my knowledge) for other RDBMS.

So sadly you still need to rely on your string concatenation for now until we can improve the current API, or in the spirit of Open Source, help us discussing the use case and brainstorm how we can solve it.